# C#: Connection between IFormattable, IFormatProvider and ICustomFormatter, and when to use what

Tags: c#, formatting

What are the difference and connection between `IFormattable`, `IFormatProvider` and `ICustomFormatter` and when would they be used? A simple implementation example would be very nice too.

And I don't really mean when it is used in the .net framework, but when I would implement these myself and in that case what classes would typically implement what interface and how to do it properly.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

- `IFormattable` is an object which supports formats in `string.Format`, i.e. the `xxx` in `{0:xxx}`. `string.Format` will delegate to an object's `IFormattable.ToString` method if the object supports the interface.
- `IFormatProvider` is a source of configuration information that formatters use for things like culture-specific date and currency layout.
- However, for situations like e.g. `DateTime`, where the instance you want to format already implements `IFormattable` yet you don't control the implementation (`DateTime` is supplied in the BCL, you can't replace it easily), there is a mechanism to prevent `string.Format` from simply using `IFormattable.ToString`. Instead, you implement `IFormatProvider`, and when asked for an `ICustomFormatter` implementation, return one. `string.Format` checks the provider for an `ICustomFormatter` before it delegates to the object's `IFormattable.Format`, which would in turn likely ask the `IFormatProvider` for culture-specific data like `CultureInfo`.

Here is a program which shows what `string.Format` asks the `IFormatProvider` for, and how the flow of control goes:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

class MyCustomObject : IFormattable
{
    public string ToString(string format, IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ToString(\"{0}\", provider) called", format);
        return "arbitrary value";
    }
}

class MyFormatProvider : IFormatProvider
{
    public object GetFormat(Type formatType)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Asked for {0}", formatType);
        return CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.GetFormat(formatType);
    }
}

class App
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(
            string.Format(new MyFormatProvider(), "{0:foobar}", 
                new MyCustomObject()));
    }
}
```

It prints this:

```
Asked for System.ICustomFormatter
ToString("foobar", provider) called
arbitrary value
```

If the format provider is changed to return a custom formatter, it takes over:

```
class MyFormatProvider : IFormatProvider
{
    public object GetFormat(Type formatType)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Asked for {0}", formatType);
        if (formatType == typeof(ICustomFormatter))
            return new MyCustomFormatter();
        return CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.GetFormat(formatType);
    }
}

class MyCustomFormatter : ICustomFormatter
{
    public string Format(string format, object arg, IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        return string.Format("(format was \"{0}\")", format);
    }
}
```

When run:

```
Asked for System.ICustomFormatter
(format was "foobar")
```

Comment: Why do you return `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.GetFormat` in `MyFormatProvider.GetFormat`? And what would you use the `IFormatProvider` for in `MyCustomFormatter.Format`?

Comment: The default format provider is CultureInfo.CurrentCulture; it's the one that's used if you don't specify one in one of the overloads to `string.Format`. I already explained what you'd use IFormatProvider for - to provide configuration info (e.g. ask for CultureInfo), for things like date formatting (e.g. to use CultureInfo.DateTimeFormat).

Comment: Don't use `return CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.GetFormat(formatType)` in the GetFormat it will break. Eventually it will be cast into an ICustomFormatter. see: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/text/stringbuilder.cs,2c3b4c2e7c43f5a4

Comment: @Wouter every time you use `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` as `IFormatProvider` it will have `GetFormat` called on it. If that breaks, it's a problem with that instance of `CultureInfo`, since it implements `IFormatProvider`. Is there a specific implementation that you found a problem with?

Comment: See: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/decimal.cs,0b7d635398c0e319 and https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/numberformatinfo.cs,9c4284b5db21c23a for how the code path will expect a `IFormatProvider` (usually `CultureInfo`) to support `GetFormat`, if you want to print a decimal with current culture (e.g. commas vs dots for separators vs decimal). You can't provide that `CultureInfo` without it having `GetFormat` called for `ICustomFormatter` earlier.

Comment: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/cultureinfo.cs,1365  shows that it will either return NumberFormatInfo or DateTimeFormatInfo both do not implement ICustomFormatter.

Comment: @BarryKelly I want to make a custom format provider to customize a custom struct but i don't want to change anything else about the culture used for example try something like: `string.Format(new MyProvider(), "{0} {1} {2}", mystruct, 0.123, true);` Your solution doesn't work because formatType will  always be ICustomFormatter

Answer (score 2):

Custom formatting works base on the coordination between 3 components:

- Formattable
- Format provider
- Formatter

The **formattable** objects are instances that can use a format provider along with a format string to format their data by implementing the `IFormattable` interface. Basically, they will request the format provider to get a `formatter` and then use the format string which are format instructions to ask the `formatter` to format their instances. Date/time and numeric types are examples of formattable types.

The **format providers** are classes that implement the `IFormatProvider` interface. They are responsible for returning the `formatter` object base on the format type requested by the caller. The format type could be the type of whatever that a format provider could understand while the returned `formatter` should be whatever that the caller (the formattable `object in most cases) could use to format their data.

The **formatters** are objects which are responsible for providing formatting services. For date/time and numeric types, format providers are also `formatters` which are `CultureInfo`, `DateTimeFormatInfo`, and `NumberFormatInfo`.

In composite formatting implemented by some methods such as `String.Format`, `Console.WriteLine` or `StringBuilder.AppendFormat`, when a format provider is passed to them, they always ask the format provider for a `formatter` that implements the `ICustomFormatter` interface. This allows developers to provide various custom formatting to these methods.

Answer (score 0):

[`IFormattable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformattable.aspx) is an object that supports different (named/custom) formats - for example, numbers, etc. By using an interface, multiple blocks of code can use the value and a format string, and this is common (for example) in data-binding and `string.Format`.

An [`IFormatProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider.aspx) fills in some gaps dealing with formatting - particularly i18n. Most commonly, a `CultureInfo` is used as the provider, either giving a specific local format, or the invariant culture.

As far as I know, [`ICustomFormatter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icustomformatter.aspx) is unrelated, and ties more into serialization (`BinaryFormatter`). I could be wrong...

An example of an `IFormattable` object:

```
IFormattable d = 123.45M;
string s1 = d.ToString("c", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture), // local currency
       s2 = d.ToString("c", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); // invariant currency
```

Comment: This is a very old answer, but for the sake of The Children: `ICustomFormatter` is indeed about string formatting, and for adding support for format strings to types that aren't `IFormattable` implementations (or for providing different format strings to `IFormattable` objects). `IFormatter` is the one about serialization.

Comment: IFormattable is also used during string interpolation.