# DateTime day ending 24:00 (midnight)

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I have a customer that wants to see midnight represented as the end of the prior day.

Example

```
var date = DateTime.Parse("1/27/2010 0:00");
Console.WriteLine(date.ToString(<some format>));
```

Display:

```
1/26/2010 24:00
```

I believe this is valid in the ISO 8601 standard.  ([see this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-hour_clock#Midnight_00:00_and_24:00))

Is there any way to support this in .net (without an ugly string manipulation hack)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess you'll need a custom formatter for the dates. Look at the [`IFormatProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider(VS.71).aspx) and [`ICustomFormatter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icustomformatter(VS.71).aspx) interfaces.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697470/c-connection-between-iformattable-iformatprovider-and-icustomformatter-and-wh) and [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/custstrformat.aspx) may also help.

Comment: Thank you, Lucero.  I thought these interfaces might be useful. (+1) If this works, I'll post an example.

Comment: The custom formatter works with string.Format(), but ICustomFormatter.Format() never gets called when using date.ToString(new MyFormatter());

Answer (score 3):

You could setup an extension method, although the proper approach would probably be to use the IFormatProvider as [Lucero suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150052/datetime-day-ending-2400-midnight/2150086#2150086). The extension method would compare to the date's [Date property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx), which returns the date with the time component set to midnight. It would be similar to this:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string ToCustomFormat(this DateTime date)
    {
        if (date.TimeOfDay < TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1))
        {
            return date.AddDays(-1).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + " 24:00";
        }
        return date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy H:mm");
    }
}
```

Then call it using:

```
var date = DateTime.Parse("1/27/2010 0:00");
Console.WriteLine(date.ToCustomFormat());
```

EDIT: updated per comments.

Comment: There are 60,000 milliseconds in that minute and this one only works with one of them (DateTime.Today representing 0:00.000 AM)

Comment: @DrJokepu: I'm not sure I follow. Can you please elaborate? If the input is midnight as given by the OP the comparison should be fine. If milliseconds are included, such as `0:00:30`, the above will return the current day unless it is made to check against the `Hour` and `Minute` properties.

Comment: Plus 1 for the example.  I think you're right about Lucero's suggestion.

Comment: DrJokepu is right. The fix is to replace your test "date == date.Date" by something like "date.TimeOfDay < TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)".  This will display 24:00 during the whole of the first minute of the day.  Nevertheless, custom formatting is a better solution.